# get and set string onmouseover js value

Tags: javascript, delphi, twebbrowser

I want to run some `onmousedown` function, but how can I run this function without `onmousedown` event, in twebbrowser?

Can you suggest me a proper function, please?

Comment: Is this on your own web page, or on someone else's site?

Comment: What you mean _disable_. This functions can be called without default behaviour, or with error?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the function name to null, like this:

```
alert('test'); // will show 'test'
alert = null;
alert('test'); // will do nothing
```

Comment: It will throw an error because it's not a function. You'd be better off with setting it to a no-op.

Comment: in ff 6.0.2 doesn't throw anything. i guess it depends on the engine